# How to pair bluetooth device without entering pin

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE,

i would like to know how to programmatically pair **Bluetooth** without entering PIN manually the following code i am using with that it opens pairing dialog asking pin but i want direct pairing without entering pin

```
public void pairDevice2(BluetoothDevice device)
{
    String ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST = "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST";
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    String EXTRA_DEVICE = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    String EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT";
    int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 0;
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want to pair it automatically when it is scanned.

Answer (score 1):

Look at insecure Bluetooth sockets, e.g. [createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29). That way you can establish connection without pairing process.

Comment: Sorry I can't, I don't have time for that plus I think there are plenty of examples of bluetooth communication out there. Just look how to establish connection via bluetooth and then replace method createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() with createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() on client side and method listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord () with listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord() on server side.